Cartoon about lives of teenagers, including very short blonde in blue dress and a pink-haired girl in platform shoes?
I remember it was focused on a group of teenagers:

a very short blonde female, fairly certain height was a focus of at
least one episode, wore a blue dress
a short blue(?) haired male
a tall male geek, possibly with glasses
a pink haired female, wore a pink top, blue trousers and platform shoes
a blue/purple haired female

It would have been on air sometime during the mid to late 2000's, definitely in the UK and possibly elsewhere.
Pretty sure it was just following their day to day life, the name Talia rings a bell as the name of one of the characters but that could easily be wrong

6teen??????????

it sounds to me like you are describing Girlstuff/Boystuff. The characters included Talia, Simon (He was the tall geek with glasses), Ben, Hanna, etc. There were 6 of them (3 boys and 3 girls). Here is a link to the imdb page 
